# Getting recent Bytes while recording Audio Android

Tags: java, android, file, audio, audio-recording

I am working on an Audio recording function. I want the recorded Audio to be saved into the internal cache directory of my app so that I can later process it and send it to my server. I have taken the `RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION` in my Android Manifest.

Below is the code I plan to use for recording audio and save it to a file.

```
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + uuid + ".3gp";


    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

I expect the above code to work fine but I am facing another issue. I want to create a Waveform effect for my app for which I am using this [library](https://github.com/gauravk95/audio-visualizer-android). This library works with the below code:

```
   //get a reference to the visualizer
    mVisualizer = findViewById(R.id.blast);

    //TODO: get the raw audio bytes
    
    //pass the bytes to visualizer
    mVisualizer.setRawAudioBytes(bytes);
```

Now, my question is how can I get the Bytes in real-time of the Audio which is being recorded and being saved? **Should I read the file and extract recent bytes from it at regular intervals or is there any other method to achieve this**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use other approach than `MediaPlayer`. Something like [that](https://medium.com/@NVSoftware/record-replay-and-visualize-raw-audio-data-in-android-93ad10262dd3).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Thank You for the comment. Shall have a look and update you soon.

Comment: In my case I used a webview and webRTC record, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269328/recording-audio-with-html5-the-sound-tends-to-do-clicks-like-if-it-stops-click

Comment: Hi, @AndriiOmelchenko I looked into your provided link but could not understand on how to use it exactly. Can you please provide an answer on how to use it?

Comment: @Jintor is the link that your provided meant for Android?

Comment: @RajeshK it's webRTC so I implemented it myself in my projects : desktop, mobile, android (within webview) AND ios (within webview), but for IOS it's a bit tricky ==>> looke at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737535/ios-xcode-wkwebview-and-video-tags-needs-playsinline-true-but-in-a-webview

Comment: @Jintor Thanks for the response. Realized just now that you were suggesting to use a WebView in Android and use the linked method to record the audio. But I want to use native Audio functionality as I believe your suggested method might not really useful to my other use cases such as play/pause, save multiple files, update UI while recording, edit the audio file or merge, etc. I need full control over the code which might be difficult in your suggested method. But anyways can you please submit an answer it might be helpful or someone might find it helpful in future.

Comment: @RajeshK WebRTC have tons of possibilities, play/pause while recording is possible via MediaRecorder.pause() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/pause --- also audio+video manipulations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_manipulation. ---- I develop mobile apps and I opted to go all in in webRTC because 1- it's in perpetual development, new features, etc 2- it multi platform ::: what I program in webRTC is compatible to desktop + Android + IOS , so only 1 code compatible with tons of devices...

Comment: @RajeshK Other note, while testing native VS webRTC => I realized that coding in native (anrdoid or ios) is not future proof  (and sometimes a bitch) : example you code today with xyz and 1 year later it's fu@#$ing deprecated and unusable and you have to rechange your code over and over :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the logic what you can do is take input of small intervals, say 1 second(1000 ms), and then show the waveform of that and after that save the data you got. Now after saving take new input and then add that new data in the previous data after forming a waveform (or doing any operation) of new data.

Just do these things on separate Threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please provide the sample code for inputting the new data(bytes).